# How to generalize the Australian shuffle?

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, shuffle

```
def australian(deck,n):
  i=0
  s=deck
  if len(deck) < 12:
    while i < n :
      i=i+1
      s=s[0::2]+s[1::4]+s[3::4]
      s=s[::-1]
    return(s)
  if len(deck) < 26:
    while i<n:
      i=i+1
      s=s[0::2]+s[1::4]+s[3::8]+s[7::8]
      s=s[::-1]
    return(s)
  if len (deck) < 48:
    while i<n:
      i=i+1
      s=s[0::2]+s[1::4]+s[3::8]+s[7:8]+s[15:16]
      s=s[::-1]
    return(s)
```

this is my first code for the Australian shuffle. I wanted to generalize it to make it work for a bigger deck.

I wrote a second code with a method that should work, but I can't figure out how to put it in a loop for it to work with all combinations.

```
def Down_Under_shufffle(lst):
  basic=lst[0::2]#les impaires 
  length = len(basic)
  middle_index = length//2#list/4 :: middle index = 4
  s=basic[:middle_index]
  s1=s[:2]
  s2=s1[:1]
  s3=s2[:1]
  a = [element * (2**1) for element in s]#multiplie les elemnts 
  a1= [element * (2**2) for element in s1]
  a2 = [element * (2**3) for element in s2]
  a3= [element * (2**4) for element in s3]
  toto=basic+a+a1+a2+a3
  toto=toto[::-1]
  return(toto)
print(Down_Under_shufffle([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16]))
```

Comment: It is not a random shuffle, it is deterministic, and so can be used in card tricks.  See [The Down Under deal](https://www.maa.org/external_archive/columns/colm/cardcolm200504.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think the whole thing can be simplified.  Below there are two approaches

This deals the items in arr one by one:

```
def down_under_shuffle_items( arr ):
    a = arr.copy()   # arr would be destroyed without this step.
    result = []
    while len( a ) > 1:  
        result.append( a.pop( 0 ) )  # Remove the top item and append to result
        a.append( a.pop( 0 ) )       # Remove the new top item and append to the end of a
    return result + a                # If a is empty this adds nothing
```

This deals all the even items, for me [0::2] are even, and removes them from `a`.  It then continues to loop as long as `a` has more than one item in it.
If the length of `a` is less than the length of `dealt` the first card in `a` needs to be removed and then added to the end of a.  This was faster when I tested it.

```
def down_under_shuffle( arr ):
    a = arr.copy()   # arr would be destroyed without this step 
    result = []
    while len( a ) > 1:              # Loop while a isn't empty
        dealt = a[ :: 2 ]            # deal the even cards
        a = a[ 1::2 ]                # Keep the odd cards
        result += dealt              # add dealt cards to result
        if len( a ) < len( dealt ):  # If the last card was dealt, move a[0] to a[-1], rotating a
            a.append( a.pop(0) )

    return result + a                # If a is empty this adds nothing
```

Results:

```
deck = [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 ]

down_under_shuffle_items( deck )                                                                    
# [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 1, 5, 9, 3, 11, 7]

down_under_shuffle( deck )                                                                            
# [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 1, 5, 9, 3, 11, 7]
```

Comment: help appreciated I've been stuck with this for days, also thanks for the explanation didn't know about ".pop" 